# C++ - Boost.Promise, Boost.Unique_Future and Move Semantics

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, move-semantics

I'm following some tutorials by Bartosz Milewski [here](http://www.corensic.com/Learn/Resources/ConcurrencyTutorialPartFour.aspx) which I find very useful.
However, as the author uses the [just::thread](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/) implementation of the C++11 threading standard (which I don't yet have), I have decided to go with boost threads for now as the author of the tutorial says its trivial to do so. This seems to be the case for the first three tutorials in the series but I bumped into some problems with the fourth. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <boost\thread.hpp>
#include <boost\thread\future.hpp>

void thFun(boost::promise<std::string> & prms)
{
    std::string str("Hi from future!");
    prms.set_value(str);
}

int main()
{
    boost::promise<std::string> prms;
    boost::unique_future<std::string> fut = prms.get_future();

    boost::thread th(&thFun, std::move(prms)); // error C2248: 'boost::promise<R>::promise' : cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::promise<R>' 

    std::cout << "Hi from main!";
    std::string str = fut.get();
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    th.join();

    return 0;
}
```

The following line seems to raise an issue that I don't understand:

```
boost::thread th(&thFun, std::move(prms));
```

where the compiler complains:

> error C2248: 'boost::promise::promise' : cannot access private
>   member declared in class 'boost::promise'

Can anyone suggest what the problem might be?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Boost.Threads supports move semantics, so either your compiler doesn't support it or you're not compiling in C++11 mode (`-std=c++0x` in GCC, for example).

Comment: I've used `std::move()` in other examples and had no problem so I don't think it's that - but I could be wrong. I also tried `boost::move()` but the outcome was the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`boost::thread` uses `boost::bind` to handle a thread function with additional arguments, which requires that they are copyable. You could pass the promise by pointer or reference (using e.g. `boost::ref`), but that requires that the object outlives the thread. In this example it is OK, but for a detached thread, or one which outlives the function that started it, this would prevent the use of `boost::promise` objects on the stack.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Anthony. How does the just::thread implementation differ from this?

Comment: just::thread doesn't rely on `bind`, so it can move all the arguments.